# Как проверить соприкасается ли image с другим image в Windows Form

Tags: c#

Есть ли какой нибудь готовый метод проверки на соприкосновение 2 объектов Image в Windows Form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278455/collision-detection-between-two-picturebox-in-a-winform

Answer (score 1):

У `pictureBox1.Bounds` есть метод `IntersectsWith`

```
bool isIntersects = pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds)
```